# Can hard-code address and manually assign it to a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, hardcoded

When I compile this code :

```
int main() {

  int a = 10;
  int *p = &a;

  printf("%p",p) // or printf("%p",&a);

  return 0;
}
```

it prints `0022ff38`.
Then this code :

```
int a=10;
int *p =(int *)0x22ff38;

printf("%d",*p); //does not output 10;
```

should print 10, but it output another thing`(2293560)`.

**But when I edit the code, and add a single line :**

```
  int main() {

  int a = 10;
  int *p =(int *)0x22ff38;
  
  printf("%p",&a);
  printf("%d",*p); // Now it prints correctly:10

  return 0;
}
```

Every thing is ok!.

> Questions:

1. Why my code does not output `a` value in first code?
2. What is usage of this way addressing pointers? is it useful?

**Edit :**
I have no problem in Linux, because in Linux every time that I run the code, the variable address changes and program output `segmentation fault`. but in windows address remains the same, and it is expected that *manual addressing* work in windows.

Comment: i compile with Code:: Blocks in windows 32 bit.

Comment: Modern operating systems commonly randomize certain starting locations in programs in each execution, to foil attackers that would exploit defects in programs. Some exploits rely on inserting addresses in the stack through buffer overflows, such as overwriting a correct function address with another address the attacker can use to have other code executed. Randomizing address space layout makes that difficult. So the address you print for `a` in one run is not necessarily the address `a` will have in another run.

Comment: Additionally, when you edit the source code to set `p` to a hard-coded address and recompile, the compiler may lay out memory differently, putting `a` in a different location, so the address of `a` in that program might not equal the address of `a` in the original program, even without address space layout randomization.

Comment: yes in linux every time i run code , address of variable `a` changes. but in windows every time that code builds and runs it is in same address (`0x22ff38`).

Comment: But why don't you print both `&a` and `p` ? That would answer your question...

Comment: thank you wildplasse. i test that it become ok in windows. but another strange thing occurs. when add line `printf("%p",&a)` to code every thing become ok and `printf("%d",*p)` output `10`. when delete that line,  `printf("%d",*p)` again output wrong number. what is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilers are smarter than you think. For example, given this code:

```
int main() {
  int a=10;
  int *p =(int *)0x22ff38;

  printf("%d",*p);
}
```

The compiler is going to see that `a` is never even used. So it will never bother to actually allocate any memory for it.

If you add a `printf("%d", a)`, the compiler might only put `a` in a register and never in memory.

Fundamentally, you can't assume that two programs will put variables in the same place in memory.

Comment: Yes it is true. when add line `printf("%p",&a)` , compiler puts a in memory instead of register, and `printf("%d",*p)` outputs `a` value.(`10`). is this guess true?